# How to continuously make a http request and respond with push notification if data is available

Tags: android, mysql, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, httprequest

I'm developing an app in which I wanted to implement some notifications features for the user. Every user notification is saved in a back end sql database. What I've done so far is to create a Android service in which after a certain delay, an HTTP request is made to check if database has new notifications for the user by processing its **json** reply and notify the user if something is available.

After some research I've done, I have come to conclusion that this in not battery-friendly and I "have" to use **Push Notifications** using some service like *gcm* or *fcm*.

So my problem is now this:

> How to properly make a request to the database every for example 1
>   sec. and check if any notification is available and **THEN** make a
>   push notification so that the device is triggered to fetch the
>   notifications themselves from the database?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not help me out.

Comment: you can use a timer to send what you want in the wanted time

Comment: Would be easier if you use Firebase Database as Backend, then use Cloud Functions for Firebase Database Triggers. No polling on your client side needed.